# Apache Shiro UnknownSessionException occured after logout and before next page loading

Tags: jakarta-ee, logout, shiro, omnifaces

I'm trying my luck here. I had checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188718/shiro-unknownsessionexception-after-logout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299354/how-to-solve-unknownsessionexception-thrown-in-logout-method-in-apache-shiro) to get some hint without success. I use Apache Shiro 1.4.0 on a Payara 4.1.1.171.1. The logout part in my shiro.ini is:

```
[main]
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
logout.redirectUrl = /index.xhtml

[urls]
/index.xhtml = ssl, user
/login.xhtml = ssl, user
/logout.xhtml = logout
```

On my user interface, I do have a *logout button* calling the `submit()` method defined as:

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    // some actions involving EJBs
    Faces.redirect("/logout.xhtml");
}
```

Then I have this error:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [db328e2a-8b78-40e6-afb7-72c01e10a20a]
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.AbstractSessionDAO.readSession(AbstractSessionDAO.java:170)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSessionManager.java:236)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.retrieveSession(DefaultSessionManager.java:222)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.doGetSession(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.lookupRequiredSession(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:152)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.getAttribute(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DelegatingSession.getAttribute(DelegatingSession.java:141)
    at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.getAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:121)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpSession.getAttribute(ShiroHttpSession.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.get(SessionMap.java:118)
    at org.omnifaces.util.FacesLocal.getSessionAttribute(FacesLocal.java:1505)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Hacks.removeViewState(Hacks.java:437)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.unloadView(OmniViewHandler.java:136)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.restoreView(OmniViewHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1696)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I put some `LOGGER.debug(...)` in filter and my involved classes to know when this happens, assuming that filtering is sequential, and it appears that **this error happens after logout filter `afterCompletion()` method and before the next page (namely the login page) loads**.

So I struggle to find the guilty component. If anyone has an idea about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 'logout' is getting called twice, or you are trying to use a session after a user has been 'logged out'

Does your `/logout.xhtml` have any logic that is requires a user session?
(The logout filter will run before the rendering of your page)

Comment: the `/logout.xhtml` does not exists, the URL is only used to have a logout URL. I haven't thought about the logout filter getting called twice because it didn't show up in my log. For sure, something is trying to use a session after a logout but the point is I have no idea which class as none of of the logs points to any of my classes :( I'll try to dig further the "logout called twice". Maybe that was the hint. Thanks

Comment: After further investigation, it seems that some OmniFaces's ViewScoped beans were not completely destroyed when logout occurs. At that moment, when redirecting to /index.xhtml, OmniFaces tries to unload (or restore, I'm not sure) the view corresponding to such beans. OmniFaces want to get some information from a logged out session, hence the exception. I could not identity the guilty beans yet as I have many of them. Most likely, OmniFaces tried to fetch the logical view attribute or something similar